# Auxiliary verb position in questions with "why"

Tags: questions, passive-voice, infinitives, past-participles, do-support

Of these two options which one is correct?

> Why doesn't the website get loaded?

or

> Why the website doesn't get loaded?

Maybe the more natural one is:

> Why isn't the website loaded?

but I'm wondering if either of the first two is correct.

Comment: Questions with *wh-* words require the construction *Whxx AUX SUBJECT VERB etc*. An auxiliary verb or a form of *be* must follow the *wh-* word.

Comment: @StoneyB, why is it that you answer in the comments instead of answering in the, uh, answers?

Comment: @Codeswitcher Time. and Opportnity.

Comment: @StoneyB I can see that.  Scrolling down to the bottom of the page isn't something you can do every day.  And doing so is so very time consuming.

Comment: @Codeswitcher That is not an answer. It is a possible component of an answer. Answers take half an hour to two hours to write.

Comment: @StoneyB, maybe we should take this to meta -- I'm curious what you feel an answer requires to be an answer.  I mean, must an answer be complete to be an answer?  Often questions to ELL have two implicit dimensions, the "what are the principles that pertain here?" and the "how do I use them here?"  It seems to me that different contributors have different strengths in those two areas, and the SE affordances nicely support different answerers each contributing answers which address each part, absolving individuals of having to be completist.  But I'm open to argument on this.

Comment: @Codeswitcher I agree with you. But my comment only addresses the 'principle' which invalidates OP's second example. If I built it out it still wouldn't have anything useful to say, either theoretic or pragmatic, about the contrast between OP's first and third examples.

Comment: @StoneyB True.  However, it is still a partial answer (to why the second example isn't correct.)  Why not post it as such? Label it, "Re your second example", if you are concerned partial answers sound dismissive.  Or even "Partial Answer".

Comment: @StoneyB Also, I wanted to say I really appreciate your engaging in this conversation with me.  I am being impertinent, and imposing on your time, and I know it.  I wouldn't care much one way or another how someone else engaged with ELL, except that right now, the only criterion for promotion (from Beta) on which ELL is not rocking is average of answers per question.  Thank you for putting up with me.

Comment: @Codeswitcher There's no impertinence at all. But the only way for me to increase the A/Q ratio is by composing more answers, and I'm pretty much maxed out. I put any 'extra' time I have into looking for unanswered QQ I can take out of that category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the first two, the most natural sounding one is the first:

> Why doesn't the website get loaded?

Although you will usually find it used in the active form:

> Why doesn't the website load?

When forming a question, the verb *do* moves to the front of the sentence.

As for your third option, that would indicate that you expect the website to have been loaded already, but it is not. It is hard to think of a situation where that sentence would sound natural, except maybe if you navigate to a website, go and get some coffee, and when you come back your screen is still blank. Even then, I think that these are more natural:

> Why isn't the site loading? 
>   Why doesn't the site load?